# pl/sql Compare with previous row

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

The goal is to combine Time_a within 10 min interval that has same ID.
And group the ID.

```
ID   Time_a        ->           ID    
------------                    ----------
1    12:10:00                   1
1    12:15:00                   2
1    12:20:00                   2
2    12:25:00
2    12:35:00
2    02:00:00
```

It became two '2' because time interval between row5 and row6 is more than 10 min.
I was able to combine within 10-min difference, but it doesn't distinguish ID.

```
select ID    
from(
    select id, Time_a, min(time) OVER (order by id, time rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) prev_t_stamp
    from dual
)
where abs(Time_a-prev_t_stamp)>10/1440
```

Comment: What is the datatype of time_a?

Answer (score 0):

If time_a is date then it works as follow. If it is a timestamp you need to cast it to a date otherwise it will not quite work. Here is my test script

```
drop table test;
create table test (id number, time_a date);
insert into test values (1, to_date('12:10','HH24:MI'));
insert into test values (1, to_date('12:15','HH24:MI'));
insert into test values (1, to_date('12:20','HH24:MI'));
insert into test values (2, to_date('12:25','HH24:MI'));
insert into test values (2, to_date('12:35','HH24:MI'));
insert into test values (2, to_date('14:00','HH24:MI'));

select id from (
select distinct id, case from (
select ID,case when abs(Time_a-prev_t_stamp)>10/1440 then '>' end case
from(
    select id, Time_a, min(time_a) OVER (order by id, time_a rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) prev_t_stamp
    from test
)
)
) order by 1
```

This results into:

```
table TEST dropped.
table TEST created.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.

ID
--
 1 
 2 
 2
```